# errno: 150 Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, migrate

i have laravel 5.5 project 
in migration i wright this

```
Schema::create('item_gifts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('item_gift_name');
    $table->integer('item_gift_item_id_from')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('item_gift_item_id_from')->references('id')->on('items');           
    $table->integer('item_gift_item_id_to')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('item_gift_item_id_to')->references('id')->on('items');             
    $table->integer('item_gift_quantity');
    $table->integer('item_gift_min_order');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

but i always gat this error

```
In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `lar
  avel`.`#sql-2830_22f` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
   incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `item_gifts` add con
  straint `item_gifts_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`)
   references `items` (`id`))


In Connection.php line 458:

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `lar
  avel`.`#sql-2830_22f` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
   incorrectly formed")
```

what i need is to connect item_gift_item_id_from in item_gifts with id in items 
i tried many solutions but nothing is work 
thanks ..

Comment: The error says about `user_id` and you don't have it in the migration you've shown.

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `lar
  avel`.`#sql-2830_24a` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
   incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `item_gifts` add con
  straint `item_gifts_item_gift_item_id_from_foreign` foreign
  key (`item_gift_item_id_from`) references `items` (`id`))


In Connection.php line 458:

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `lar
  avel`.`#sql-2830_24a` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
   incorrectly formed")

Comment: Please show migration for the `items` table.

Comment: i didnot have migration for items i just have manually created table with one column as auto increment id CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: Where is user_id coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error, because you've manually created the items table and ID is just an integer in it:

```
CREATE TABLE items ( id int(11) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Create a new migration and make it execute before the `item_gists` one:

```
Schema::create('item_gifts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

Comment: its signed and autoincrement

Comment: @AwarPulldozer it's not unsigned. Laravel's `increments()` makes it `unsigned`

Answer (score 2):

try this code :

```
public function up()
{
Schema::create('item_gifts', function($table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->string('item_gift_name');
   $table->integer('item_gift_item_id_from')->unsigned();
   $table->integer('item_gift_item_id_to')->unsigned();
   $table->integer('item_gift_quantity');
   $table->integer('item_gift_min_order');
   $table->timestamps();
});

  Schema::table('item_gifts', function($table) {
   $table->foreign('item_gift_item_id_from')->references('id')->on('items');           
  $table->foreign('item_gift_item_id_to')->references('id')->on('items'); 
 });

}
```

Comment: ive tried this and gat same error  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `lar
  avel`.`#sql-2830_25f` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
   incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `item_gifts` add con
  straint `item_gifts_item_gift_item_id_from_foreign` foreign
  key (`item_gift_item_id_from`) references `items` (`id`))


In Connection.php line 458:

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `lar
  avel`.`#sql-2830_25f` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
   incorrectly formed")